# Showing Recent Messages Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code xcode12

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

After adding firebase pod in my code i am getting the following error

Here are my pod files

```
#pod 'AFNetworking'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'

  pod 'SAMKeychain'
  pod 'PaperTrailLumberjack/Swift'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'Localytics', '~> 5.5.0'
  pod 'AppAuth', '1.4.0'
#  pod 'LPMessagingSDK','5.0.0.960-Swift-5.1.2'
  pod 'LPMessagingSDK'
  pod 'AppCenter'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  # Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  # Add the pod for Firebase Cloud Messaging
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```

Showing Recent Messages Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

[image]

Comment: Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, include your podfile, cocoapods version, os version.

Comment: That error appears to be centered around SAMKeychain.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after installing Firebase with Swift Package Manager, and what did it for me was :

- go to your project target in "Build Phases".
- in the "Run Script" section, comment the line "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" like shown on the picture.

[image]